# Connecting Braille Display to Iphone

Tags: ios, voiceover

We are developing a braille display which can be connected to iphone via HM10. I can connect the HM10 to iphone via dabble. Now I am looking for the communication sequence and commands for pairing the display in voiceover on mode. can somebody help?

Comment: You will need a Bluetooth module that implements the legacy SPP/RFComm profile, not a BLE module like HM10.

Comment: Can you suggest any Bluetooth module that implements the legacy SPP/RFComm profile. But can't we build the protocol on BLE? because once we connect to the iPhone, then it will be  in our hand. This is my assumption, might be wrong.

Comment: The hc05 or hc06 modules might work for you. The accessibility settings screen in iOS only looks for SPP devices, so if you want the Braille display to work with voiceover in iOS you need to use that profile.

Comment: Will try HC for sure. but the question is still the same. where can I find the communication protocol to be implemented? for example, there will be a specific format in which we need to advertise product as a braille display, then only the Iphone will accept the pairing request. Where to find this documentation? Apple site is worse when it comes to support.

Comment: I couldn't find any details on any specific protocol.  I believe that iOS just looks for devices with SPP and VoiceOver sends the data as a serial stream.